# Using .compare with a property that returns a list

Tags: sql, guidewire, gosu

I'm using query.make to populate a list of users within a specific region. Originally, I used .where to pull the regions into memory, but this is inefficient because there's a large number of them. I want to rewrite the query using .compare to filter the regions before moving them to memory. However, in the original code, I use the ZoneList() function to get a list of zones from the Region entity. I'm not sure how to do that with a .compare. Any help would be a appreciated.

Original:

```
Users = Query.make(entity.URegn).select().where(\ r -> r.Region.ZoneList.hasMatch(\ o -> o.equals(ZipCode))).toSet()*.User.where(\ u -> u.Credential.Active)
```

URegn has a Region foreign key.

```
zipUsers = Query.make(entity.UserRegion).join("Region").compare("Region.Zonelist", Equals, polZip).select().toSet()*.User.where(\ u -> u.Credential.Active)*/
```

This is what I attempted and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

List all the entities you are using on the requirement and respective foriegn keys.And also provide the predicates(to be used in 'where') to be used on each entities. It helps to provide proper answer.